# Django when a data is entered, write the data in the other model depending on the condition

Tags: python, django

Hello There is a data(text) in data b on app1. I want to write the data here on d on app2. how can I do that?

```
app.model;
class Post(models.Model):
    a=models.CharField()
    b=models.TextField()

app2.model;
class Post2(models.Model):
    c=models.CharField()
    d=models.TextField()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Do you want to copy from Post to Post 2 on save? Please show your views.py

Comment: Yes Luis exactly i want to save data from Post to Post2 but only "b" table "b" to "d"

Comment: Ok, can you please show your views.py?